# Java POJO Modelling

Tags: java, json, pojo

I want a POJO to contain a Status field (only two possible values SUCCESS, FAILED) and depending on this status, the second field needs to be

1. either a POJO object( if Status is SUCCESS)
2. or just String error message(if Status is FAILED)

What should be the data type of the second field in POJO?

```
public class MyBean {
    private Status status,
    private ??? body
}
```

Comment: That's pretty broad.  Could be an identifier to an external message, using i18n to support multiple languages.  Could be a String.  Might even be a callback that provides the success message.

Comment: Please stop changing the tags. This has nothing to do with anything Java 8 specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON is also a String, So you can define it as String itself.

When exchanging data between a browser and a server, the data is mostly text and represented in JSON format.

```
public class MyBean {
    private Status status;
    private String body;
}
```

Comment: but that JSON has also a corresponding POJO. I want it basically to contain an object of that POJO in case of SUCCESS status

Comment: maybe I can keep the data type as String only, and cast my POJO to JSON  and then store it.

Comment: But please suggest if you have a better solution. Thanks :)

Comment: Yea thats what ideally we do, You get the response in JSON and then you map it to a particular model. For example there are many libraries which you can use to map it like Object Mapper.